# How to access Virtual Slides Methods of Swiper Angular Component

Tags: angular, module, swiper.js

I would like to access [virtual slides methods](https://swiperjs.com/api/#virtual) of [Swiper Angular Component](https://swiperjs.com/angular/#virtual-slides).  I need to manually trigger component re-render after slides have changed. I think I can achieve this by calling `mySwiper.virtual.update()` methode.   I tried to gain access through @ViewChild decorator

```
   @ViewChild('swiper') swiper: Swiper;  
       ngAfterViewInit(){
       // to see which properties are available
        console.dir(this.swiper);}
```

but this.swiper is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this documentation [Swiper Angular](https://swiperjs.com/angular/)

Create a reference to your swiper & You must instantiate swiper on AfterViewInit - your.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('newSwiper') newSwiper: any;

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.newSwiper.swiperRef);
    //Swiper instance will be displayed in console
  }
```

In your HTML file, do as below

```
<swiper [slidesPerView]="1" #newSwiper> 
//slides here
</swiper>
```

Now you can access properties and methods such as slideTo(), slideNext(), slidePrev() and etc.

```
this.newSwiper.swiperRef.virtual.update()
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Sorry I do not see relevant difference between my an your code. I think important pieces of information are missing.

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check if that is the one that has been missed. edit HTML file

Comment: I was missing information about  #newSwiper and what to import. Your updated answer gives enough information to access virtual.update() method. https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-angular-example-kjknzg?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";
import { SwiperComponent } from "swiper/angular";

@Component({
  selector: "app-swiper-example",
  template: `
    <swiper #swiperRef>
      <ng-template swiperSlide>slide 1</ng-template>
      <ng-template swiperSlide>slide 2</ng-template>
    </swiper>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("swiperRef", { static: false }) swiperRef: SwiperComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.dir(this.swiperRef);
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this explain usage of virtual methods?